# estoy configurando mi proyecto con maven en eclipse utilizando framework spring y me muestra el siguiente errror:

Tags: java, maven

Estoy llevando un tutorial de Spring framework mvc v3 con JPA, utilizando maven en Eclipse. Entonces he creado el proyecto y me muestra el siguiente error:

> the superclass javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet was not found on the java build path

[image: imagen]

Comment: mirate esto a ver si te ayuda http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756153/the-superclass-javax-servlet-http-httpservlet-was-not-found-on-the-java-build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es agregar la dependencia a la librería de servlets. Puesto que indicas que trabajas con maven, esta sería la dependencia:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <!--
        scope provided porque no debes agregar estas librerías
        directamente al proyecto, el contenedor de servlets
        o servidor de aplicaciones que uses se encargará de
        brindar estas librerías
    -->
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Adaptado de: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22756202/1065197

Comment: en que parte esta la libreria de servlets, porfavor, muchas gracias

Comment: Cuando colocas esta dependencia, se van a descargar las librerías en una carpeta de maven y luego el IDE asociará por ti las librerías al proyecto. Luego, en tiempo de ejecución, estas librerías estarán dentro del contenedor de servlets, es decir, dentro de Tomcat. En el caso de Tomcat, las puedes ver dentro de la carpeta lib.

Comment: muy agradecida, este es el link del tutorial que estoy llevando: http://www.uv.es/grimo/teaching/SpringMVCv3PasoAPaso/

Comment: Actualmente, Spring se encuentra en la versión 4 y el equipo se encuentra trabajando en la versión 5 del framework. Te recomiendo seguir el tutorial actualizado a la versión 4 que se indica allí: http://www.uv.es/grimo/teaching/SpringMVCv4PasoAPaso/index.html